# How to Enable SSL offloading on IIS Reverse Proxy

Tags: windows, iis, reverse-proxy, arr

I have just enabled Reverse Proxy for my NodeJS application on Windows Server by enabling Application Request Routing (ARR) and editing the web.config file by following this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Now, everything is working fine, I am able to access my NodeJS application running on localhost from an external client outside the server. I want to enforce Https connection to this reverse proxy I've just created. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Tons of duplicates over the internet https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9953/38/iis-redirect-http-to-https

Comment: Yes, I agree. There are duplicates. But I didn't find any matching my implementation, every other solution requires an IIS website or a server farm. I don't have any if you check out the article reference, you will see that I enabled proxy in ARR module, and then updated the web.confg file in `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot\` without creating a new website or a server farm

Comment: I don't have any item under the server farm, and under the sites, I only have a Default Web Site. I come from a Linux background and never worked on a Windows machine or an IIS server, I want to access the software by running cmd commands in Windows

Comment: The article you just shared requires a new site to be created before proceeding, but I don't have any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIS URL Rewrite extension could accomplish this task.
Please Install the extension.
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite
In order to force HTTP connection to https connection, please
add the below Url rules in the `webconfig` file which can be recognized by IIS.

```
<system.webServer>
           <rewrite>
            <rules>
              <rule name="Force SSL (https)" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
                <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                  <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
              </rule>
            </rules>
          </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
```

Alternatively, we could manually set up the rule by using the URL Rewrite extension after installation.
[image]
[image]
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Where do you configure the SSL offload?